# MapR quick Installer throws an error

Tags: hadoop, mapr

I am using MapR quick install version 5.0 to install hadoop and I get below error.
**MapR CLDB failed to come on line within 600 seconds**

I am using the community edition

Below is the log file

> 2016-02-17 23:37:26.753: debug msg="CLDB nodes - {{
>   mapr.groups.cldb|join(', ') }}" -> ok: {
>       "msg": "CLDB nodes - wadev-mapr-n1" } 2016-02-17 23:52:54.573:  failed: [wait_for_cldb.sh MAX_WAIT=600] [wadev-mapr-n3] => {"failed":
>   true} MapR CLDB failed to come on line within 600 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to setup MapR cluster? I was able successfully setup MapR cluster by using below link.

Here is the link:

Do:

1. wget http://package.mapr.com/releases/installer/mapr-­setup.sh
2. bash ./mapr-­setup.sh

This will give you a url with port 9443.

Comment: Which version did you use?

Comment: I used 5.1, which version are you trying to install?